# Java Multipart file to blob then back to Image has loads of random characters

Tags: java, image, jsp, base64, blob

I am recieveing an image from a jsp, converting into a byte, then blob and saving it in my Database, on a different page I am then retriving it, and when I retrieve the image I get the following String.

```
'x*??{[?Y?>YE *?????_/???????~%?+y?`??uH????#??\t?????|B??k?-??Z4V?U7?F???m+(?? ? I??pq^?Q???????18?R???-???>0~?sXxCI?;[;t???9?fBX?Bp?A??^M?k? ??G?S?u???????r?U&‚w*??8????`??> Y?2?????1?j$??\??DR[??t0? pps?_Ex? ???_o?*?? xV)?6D8?$??!?9??~???N?`???}W?s?gNUf?Mn>?s?3?r?3M???X???Q????N!pr~?W????Mjq5??????2m???8????x??V?????????[???"??*,I?/@s?V?d?B?/?Vb?&R?n|?>??2????)?r??1??%7?Q??^f?R?C?????mvm??%6?K?p??;O?Z?&?????u?????\???R"ZOex???VkE???????_??????K?M@=??o?Z[?[hb?H?V????
```

I have cut this down manually on here.
This is the tag that I have done.

```
     <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,${img}" width="100" height="100"></img>
```

I'm not quite sure what has gone wrong here, here is where I have taken the file and made it into a byte[] then a blob.

```
    byte[] byteData = file.getBytes();
    Blob blobs = new SerialBlob(byteData);
```

and how then I've converted it into a base64 string.

```
    String base64DataString = new String(byteData , "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(base64DataString);
    model.addAttribute("img", base64DataString);
```

If anyone has any idea how I can turn this string into a normal base64 string which can be used to reproduce an image, that would be very helpful.
Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String base64DataString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byteData);
```

Binary data should never be converted to String, which contains Unicode, mostly as UTF-16 chars, where every byte costs 2 bytes (one char), and the conversion takes time and probably goes wrong.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. That was probably a stupid idea of me doing that.

Comment: In fact this is a relatively frequent pitfall of developers with a C/C++ background where char might be interpreted as byte.